# Usage for displayNewMessageForm with unsaved attachments possible?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi

We are working on an Office AddIn for Outlook and we need to open a new message with predefined data we are getting from our own rest-interface in Json format like this:

```
{ 
   "attachmentNo": "1",
   "Content-Type": "application/pdf;",
   "name": "CPV - Lohnbeilage Planwahl_2018_Lohnbeilage_D.PDF",
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding": "base64",
   "Content-Disposition": "attachment;",
   "filename": "CPV - Lohnbeilage Planwahl_2018_Lohnbeilage_D.PDF",
   "content": "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxID....",
   "fileType": "pdf",
   "fileSize":"15MB"
}
```

To provide an attachment for the *displayNewMessageForm* Method I need the format:

```
{
   type: 'file',
   name: "CPV - Lohnbeilage Planwahl_2018_Lohnbeilage_D.PDF",
   url: ???,
   isInline: false
}
```

Is there any possibility to use something like a data-url like this:

```
'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxID....'
```

as url or is there another trick how I can manage to add an unsaved attachment to the new message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to pass base64 attachments as part of the displayNewMessageForm API. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins) page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Meanwhile we do have an API that lets you add base64 attachments to the current Item ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/office/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/office.context.mailbox.item?view=office-js#addfileattachmentfrombase64asyncbase64file-attachmentname-options-callback)). What you can do is the following: once the new form opens, open the add-in, call into this API to add the attachment. Note that this API is in preview (prone to changes) and currently only available in Outlook Desktop for build numbers > 16.0.10730.1000.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have added a feature request and I will try to implement it with addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async, even if we do need it for owa too.